# Is there a way to save a Seaborn or matplotlib plot as an html string/object?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Is there a method that will allow me to save my seaborn or matplotlib chart as an html string? I'm trying to embed multiple (about 20) charts into an automated report that will go out daily via email. The other aspects of my report are grounded in html. Just want to confirm that I have to rely on image only objects from seaborn/matplotlib.

I orgianlly was using altair and embedding the json into my email, however this fails to render in any email app as most email applications have javascript/css disabled.

Comment: Why don’t you save altair charts as html ? Instead of json?

Comment: When saving charts as html, it still embeds the chart using json formatting. I was curious if there was a way to do it using strictly html

Comment: I dont think so. Most of the time i see either embedded images, or gifs for interactive charts.

Answer (score 0):

HTML allows you to show any image encoded using base64, consider following example of small red dot

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4
  //8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

taken from [How to Display Base64 Images in HTML](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html.html). In your case you need:  base64-encoded PNG image generated using `seaborn`, you can use [`base64`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) for that following way

```
import base64
import seaborn as sns
fig = sns.heatmap([[1,2],[3,4]]).get_figure()
fig.savefig('heatmap.png')
with open('heatmap.png','rb') as f:
    b64data = base64.b64encode(f.read())  # b64data is bytes, use b64data.decode() if you need str
```

Comment: Use an `io.BytesIO` stream to avoid going through the disk.